# (Do not display relationship values)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entity with name of the article and article Category.
and they have one-to-many relationships.
I use  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
but I cant see data of article category(category_id) in spring data rest.

---

ArticleCategory.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_category")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ArticleCategory implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "articleCategory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();


}
```

---

Article.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Article implements Serializable {

    public Article() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private ArticleCategory articleCategory;


    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String image_url;

    @Column(name = "short_description")
    private String short_description;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "keywords", nullable = true)
    private String keywords;

    @Column(name = "visit", nullable = false)
    private int visit;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private UUID code;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "date_updated", nullable = false)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date dateUpdated;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;


    public Article(String title, String image_url, String short_description, String text, String keywords, int visit, UUID code) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.short_description = short_description;
        this.text = text;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.visit = visit;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

---

Article Repository

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "article", path = "article")

public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article,Long> {

    Article findByCode(UUID uuid);


}
```

---

And this is output of spring data rest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djhGP.png)

Comment: Can your please show me your `Controller` and `Service`?

Comment: Here you can not define what is your problem

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I have not created them yet , i use spring data rest

Comment: @امیررضااندیشمند please re-edit your question to improve formating. In its current state, it is impossible to read. Thanks! Additionally, please provide the JSON that is generated when you actually use `@JsonIdentityInfo`. The one that you currently show is the outcome of the usage of `@JsonManagedReference `and `@JsonBackReference` as your original question was describing (that is another thing to not do in any case, change the scope of the question, otherwise you might invalidate previous answers). Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias Ok thanks for you -I re-edited the question and updated the output as well

Comment: That is not what I suggested. You need to also use `@JsonIdentityInfo` in `ArticleCategory`. Please try it and let me know the outcome.

Comment: @JoãoDias i JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id") I added to the article category but the output did not change . Should I edit the question based on that?

Comment: @JoãoDias I do not understand where the problem is

Comment: That is simply not possible. Try to remove `@JsonIdentityInfo` from both classes and try again. If you don't get an infinite recursion exception then you are not rebuilding your application properly.

Comment: @JoãoDias I removed JsonIdentityInfo from both classes and the program ran and no exceptions

Comment: @JoãoDias what should i do?

Comment: @JoãoDias I created a class for ArticleDataIntializer to add data. Could this be due to a mistake in adding data (but the data has been added to the tables)?

Comment: If you had no exceptions then you can't possibly have any data in your database otherwise you would get an infinite recursion exception.

Comment: It is very hard to help you further without additional code and debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the controller
And that's why @JsonManageRefrence and @JsonBackRefrence do not work

I replaced the lazy load with the eager load in both entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Eager)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonManageRefrence
private User user;



 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "articleCategory", 
 fetch = FetchType.Eager)
    @JsonBackRefrence
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();
```

and then add a controller

```
package com.example.demo;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getAllArticle")
public class MyController {

    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    // you must do constructor injection

@GetMapping("/getAllArticle")
public List<Article> allArticle()
{
    return  articleRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly because you used `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`. Keep in mind the following when using them:

- `@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of the relationship and is the one that gets serialized normally.
- `@JsonBackReference` is the back part of the relationship and it will be omitted from serialization.
- The serialized `Article` object does not contain a reference to the `ArticleCategory` object.

---

If you want to have any `ArticleCategory` data when serializing `Article` you can either use `@JsonIdentityInfo` so that one of the properties is serialized (in this case I've chosen `id` for both):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Article implements Serializable{ 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private ArticleCategory articleCategory;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_category")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class ArticleCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "articleCategory" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article> articles=new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

If you are only interested in `categoryId` another possibility would be to use `@JsonIgnore` on `private Set<Article> articles` property so that it is not serialized:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_category")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ArticleCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "articleCategory" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article> articles=new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

If none of those suits your needs you might need to implement your own custom serializer. You can read more about all those options at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your information.
I tried these methods but to no avail

Comment: What does that mean? What was the result when you applied the suggestions? At least `@JsonIgnore` will work as you intend for sure. Did you remove `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` while trying any of the suggested approaches?

Comment: i use JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id") in Article class and remove JsonManagedRefrence and jsonBackRefrence  but the result has not changed and i use JsonIgnoe up   private Set<Article> articles but But that has not changed

Comment: Can you please add the complete `Article` and `ArticleCategory` to your answer? Additionally, can you please add your Spring Data Rest interface? Thanks!